# Determining time to collision

Tags: java, android, c++

I am working on an android application that will determine distance from an obstacle infront of the camera. if I calculate the time to collision, I will be able to determine distance. I am able to obtain the optical flow vectors, how do I continue from there to determine time to collision.
this is what I have so far;

```
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    if (mMOP2fptsPrev.rows() == 0) {

        //Log.d("Baz", "First time opflow");
        // first time through the loop so we need prev and this mats
        // plus prev points
        // get this mat
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, matOpFlowThis, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

        // copy that to prev mat
        matOpFlowThis.copyTo(matOpFlowPrev);

        // get prev corners
        Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(matOpFlowPrev, MOPcorners, iGFFTMax, 0.05, 20);
        mMOP2fptsPrev.fromArray(MOPcorners.toArray());

        // get safe copy of this corners
        mMOP2fptsPrev.copyTo(mMOP2fptsSafe);
        }
    else
        {
        //Log.d("Baz", "Opflow");
        // we've been through before so
        // this mat is valid. Copy it to prev mat
        matOpFlowThis.copyTo(matOpFlowPrev);

        // get this mat
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, matOpFlowThis, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

        // get the corners for this mat
        Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(matOpFlowThis, MOPcorners, iGFFTMax, 0.05, 20);
        mMOP2fptsThis.fromArray(MOPcorners.toArray());

        // retrieve the corners from the prev mat
        // (saves calculating them again)
        mMOP2fptsSafe.copyTo(mMOP2fptsPrev);

        // and save this corners for next time through


    Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(matOpFlowPrev, matOpFlowThis, mMOP2fptsPrev, mMOP2fptsThis, mMOBStatus, mMOFerr);

    cornersPrev = mMOP2fptsPrev.toList();
    cornersThis = mMOP2fptsThis.toList();
    byteStatus = mMOBStatus.toList();

    y = byteStatus.size() - 1;

    for (x = 0; x < y; x++) {
        if (byteStatus.get(x) == 1) {
            pt = cornersThis.get(x);
            pt2 = cornersPrev.get(x);



            Core.circle(mRgba, pt, 5, colorRed, iLineThickness - 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that this should be the other way around: `if I calculate the time to collision, I will be able to determine`. It's easier to calculate the distance than the collision time

Comment: Ok, how can I then calculate the distance given I have the optical vectors